# Cannot get embedded map to load

Tags: html, iframe, openstreetmap

I've been trying to get an embedded map working on my college server as part of a project I've been doing. I've been using uMap (a map editor for OpenStreetMap) and just HTML (not a technical guy) - specifically the iframe tag - to get it working.

The page and embedded map display fine when accessed from the HTML file I have saved on my laptop, but the embedded map refuses to load when I try to access it via the college server I'm trying to host it on.

Here's the portion of the HTML code whereI have the map embedded. As you can see it's very straightforward and uses no coding besides HTML.

```
  <div id="mapContainer">
    <div id="map">
      <iframe width="80%" height="580px" frameborder="5px" allowfullscreen src="https://u.osmfr.org/m/884191/"></iframe>
      <p><a href="https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/map/idm-project-trinity-college_884191#16/53.3441/-6.2547">See full screen</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The only relevant error displayed in the console is "DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" - which disappears when I disable JS and CSS source maps in the devtools settings - though the map still doesn't load. The map area only says "u.osmfr.org refused to connect." - I've changed all links to https per the advice on similar problems I've seen people have.

The only other clue I can glean from the console is the link to the embedded map shows as status - failed in the network tab, not 404

Comment: Since you did not provide any error such as console outputs, it is only possible to say that your college network might be the problem. If they limit access of the url itself it won't load.

Comment: The only relevant error displayed in the console is "DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" - which disappears when I disable JS and CSS source maps in the devtools settings - though the map still doesn't load. The map area only says "u.osmfr.org refused to connect." - I've changed all links to https per the advice on similar problems I've seen people have.

Comment: The only other clue I can glean from the console is the link to the embedded map shows as status - failed in the network tab, not 404

Answer (score 0):

When I exchange the URL in the `<iframe ... src="">` statement by a URL that really responds then the content appears.

Ergo the code is OK, but not the destination content:

```html
curl "http://u.osmfr.org/m/884191/"

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
    <p>Object moved permanently -- see URI list</p>
</body>

</html>
```